# navigation controller custom search bar not disappearing?

Tags: ios, swift

I created a custom search bar and embedding it in the navigation bar, it appears but after I push another view controller, the search bar does not get replaced with the title of the pushed view controller. The search bar stays persistent throughout all views, instead of getting replaced with a title. Perfect example is Instagram search tab, you search for a person and click on the cell, their profile is pushed and the search bar is replaced with the custom title, back button, etc.

First VC

```
 self.customSearchBar.tag = 4
 self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(customSearchBar)
```

Second VC

```
if let nav: UINavigationController = self.navigationController {
   if let searchBar = nav.view.viewWithTag(4) {
        searchBar.removeFromSuperview()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a searchbar on navigationBar, this is the way.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(customSearchBar)
```

To remove it when you push it to other viewController. Write the following code in the secondVC that is pushed inside it's `viewDidLoad()` function. Also, set the tag of `customSearchBar` to any number (`TAG`)

```
if let nav: UINavigationController = self.navigationController {
   let bar: UINavigationBar = nav.navigationBar
   if let searchBar = bar.viewWithTag(TAG) {
        searchBar.removeFromSuperview()
   }
}
```

In the question, the `customSearchBar` is added to `self.navigationController.view`. To remove it, you can do the following:

```
if let nav: UINavigationController = self.navigationController {
   if let searchBar = nav.view.viewWithTag(TAG) {
        searchBar.removeFromSuperview()
   }
}
```

**Edit:**

Adding and removing a UIViewController's view as a subview of other UIViewController

```
// for adding

let viewController: ViewController = ViewController()
self.addChildViewController(viewController)
self.view.addSubview(viewController.view)

viewController.view.bounds = self.view.bounds // better to use autolayout here

viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

// for removing

if let vc = self.childViewControllers.last {
    vc.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    vc.view.removeFromSuperview()
    vc.removeFromParentViewController()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't place the searchbar inside the navigationcontroller view as this view is the same instance on all pushed viewcontrollers.

Add the searchbar to the the depending view controllers ui.

Comment: So how would I differentiate `navigationController` in specific view controller  vs all instances?

Comment: If you thing of adding views to the navigation bar add them to the navigation bar as subview and remove it before transitioning, but really try avoiding this pattern .... searchbars shouldn't be in a navigation bar but on the view controller. If you think of buttons (set bar button items an the navigationitem of the view controller, these are automatically handled)